# Some weights of XLNetForQuestionAnswering were not initialized from the model checkpoint at xlnet-base-cased and are newly initialized:

Tags: python, pytorch, torch

Some weights of XLNetForQuestionAnswering were not initialized from the model checkpoint at xlnet-base-cased and are newly initialized: ['start_logits.dense.weight', 'answer_class.dense_0.weight', 'answer_class.dense_0.bias', 'end_logits.LayerNorm.bias', 'end_logits.dense_0.weight', 'end_logits.dense_0.bias', 'end_logits.dense_1.bias', 'end_logits.dense_1.weight', 'answer_class.dense_1.weight', 'end_logits.LayerNorm.weight', 'start_logits.dense.bias']
You should probably TRAIN this model on a down-stream task to be able to use it for predictions and inference.
1
​

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.